# Control del tiempo de las vueltas de un bucle

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando una practica con funciones callback tengo un array con tres indices o posiciones, lo que quiero saber es si se puede hacer que se recorra el array y me imprima el valor de la primera posición o indice del array luego espere 2 segundos para imprimir el valor de la siguiente posición del array y así sucesivamente hasta que se empriman todos los valores del array en la consola. Con el siguiente algoritmo obtengo un resultado parecido pero no es el esperado gracias por tu apoyo.

Saludos.

```
let array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const imprime = () => {
 setInterval(() => {
   array1.forEach(ele => {
     console.log(ele)
   })
 }, 2000); 
}

imprime()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu aproximacion esta muy cerca, pero asi como esta ahora mostrara todo el array en cada iteracion, de modo que hay que hacer una pequeña modificacion para agregarle un indice que lo vaya recorriendo similarmente a un for:

```
let array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let i = 0;

interval = setInterval(() => {

    console.log(array1[i]);

    i++

    if(i == array1.length){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

}, 2000);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda saludos

Comment: Si la respuesta te fue util y el problema ya esta resuelto, podrias marcarla como aprobada.

Comment: Listo nuevamente gracias.